# My wifi will connect to a secured access but not to an open one

Tags: 16.04, networking, network-manager, intel-wireless

I am trying to connect to an open access point called Highwoods Guest, it connects but I have no internet. When I connect to one of the secured ones it will connect no problem.

What do I need to change to make it work again?

```
########## wireless info START ##########

Report from: 16 Nov 2017 08:28 EST -0500

Booted last: 16 Nov 2017 00:00 EST -0500

Script from: 25 Mar 2017 07:04 UTC +0000

##### release ###########################

Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS
Release:    16.04
Codename:   xenial

##### kernel ############################

Linux 4.4.0-98-generic #121-Ubuntu SMP Tue Oct 10 14:24:03 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Parameters: ro, quiet, splash, vt.handoff=7

##### desktop ###########################

Ubuntu

##### lspci #############################

01:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8821AE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [10ec:8821]
    Subsystem: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8821AE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [10ec:2162]
    Kernel driver in use: rtl8821ae

##### lsusb #############################

Bus 001 Device 004: ID 048d:8350 Integrated Technology Express, Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 04f3:20d3 Elan Microelectronics Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0438:7900 Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 04f2:b446 Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

##### PCMCIA card info ##################

##### rfkill ############################

0: Toshiba Bluetooth: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no
2: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no

##### lsmod #############################

toshiba_wmi            16384  0
rtl8821ae             225280  0
btcoexist              53248  1 rtl8821ae
rtl_pci                28672  1 rtl8821ae
rtlwifi                77824  2 rtl_pci,rtl8821ae
mac80211              737280  3 rtl_pci,rtlwifi,rtl8821ae
cfg80211              565248  2 mac80211,rtlwifi
sparse_keymap          16384  2 toshiba_wmi,toshiba_acpi
wmi                    20480  2 toshiba_wmi,toshiba_acpi

##### interfaces ########################

auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

##### ifconfig ##########################

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:4812 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:4812 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1 
          RX bytes:350762 (350.7 KB)  TX bytes:350762 (350.7 KB)

wlp1s0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr <MAC 'wlp1s0' [IF1]>  
          inet addr:192.168.38.205  Bcast:192.168.38.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::780b:205:9775:1a78/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:55721 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:40632 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:65408849 (65.4 MB)  TX bytes:5682488 (5.6 MB)

##### iwconfig ##########################

lo        no wireless extensions.

wlp1s0    IEEE 802.11abgn  ESSID:"CoulterandSierra"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.417 GHz  Access Point: <MAC 'CoulterandSierra' [AN10]>   
          Bit Rate=72.2 Mb/s   Tx-Power=20 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr=2347 B   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off
          Link Quality=51/70  Signal level=-59 dBm  
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:22   Missed beacon:0

##### route #############################

Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.38.1    0.0.0.0         UG    600    0        0 wlp1s0
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 wlp1s0
192.168.38.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     600    0        0 wlp1s0

##### resolv.conf #######################

nameserver 127.0.1.1

##### network managers ##################

Installed:

    NetworkManager

Running:

root       784     1  0 07:24 ?        00:00:05 /usr/sbin/NetworkManager --no-daemon

##### NetworkManager info ###############

GENERAL.DEVICE:                         wlp1s0
GENERAL.TYPE:                           wifi
GENERAL.NM-TYPE:                        NMDeviceWifi
GENERAL.VENDOR:                         Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
GENERAL.PRODUCT:                        RTL8821AE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter
GENERAL.DRIVER:                         rtl8821ae
GENERAL.DRIVER-VERSION:                 4.4.0-98-generic
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-VERSION:               N/A
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         <MAC 'wlp1s0' [IF1]>
GENERAL.MTU:                            1500
GENERAL.STATE:                          100 (connected)
GENERAL.REASON:                         0 (No reason given)
GENERAL.UDI:                            /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:02.3/0000:01:00.0/net/wlp1s0
GENERAL.IP-IFACE:                       wlp1s0
GENERAL.IS-SOFTWARE:                    no
GENERAL.NM-MANAGED:                     yes
GENERAL.AUTOCONNECT:                    yes
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-MISSING:               no
GENERAL.NM-PLUGIN-MISSING:              no
GENERAL.PHYS-PORT-ID:                   --
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     CoulterandSierra
GENERAL.CON-UUID:                       5d8770fe-ca5d-44f6-9555-16065aa0db83
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/20
GENERAL.METERED:                        no (guessed)
CAPABILITIES.CARRIER-DETECT:            no
CAPABILITIES.SPEED:                     72 Mb/s
CAPABILITIES.IS-SOFTWARE:               no
WIFI-PROPERTIES.WEP:                    yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.WPA:                    yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.WPA2:                   yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.TKIP:                   yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.CCMP:                   yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.AP:                     yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.ADHOC:                  yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.2GHZ:                   yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.5GHZ:                   yes
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTION-PATHS: /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Settings/{2,1,10}
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTIONS[1]:   5d8770fe-ca5d-44f6-9555-16065aa0db83 | CoulterandSierra
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTIONS[2]:   30eb7eae-2b95-4c9f-aca6-e8aefc269e9c | CoulterandSierra-5G
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTIONS[3]:   6ae8c37a-9711-432f-8c1c-6cf5f0b650ea | Highwoods-Guest
IP4.ADDRESS[1]:                         192.168.38.205/24
IP4.GATEWAY:                            192.168.38.1
IP4.ROUTE[1]:                           dst = 169.254.0.0/16, nh = 0.0.0.0, mt = 1000
IP4.DNS[1]:                             192.168.15.10
IP4.DNS[2]:                             192.168.15.193
DHCP4.OPTION[1]:                        requested_ms_classless_static_routes = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[2]:                        requested_domain_search = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[3]:                        requested_time_offset = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[4]:                        requested_domain_name = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[5]:                        requested_rfc3442_classless_static_routes = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[6]:                        requested_broadcast_address = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[7]:                        requested_wpad = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[8]:                        requested_netbios_scope = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[9]:                        next_server = 0.0.0.0
DHCP4.OPTION[10]:                       broadcast_address = 192.168.38.255
DHCP4.OPTION[11]:                       requested_interface_mtu = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[12]:                       requested_subnet_mask = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[13]:                       expiry = 1510921577
DHCP4.OPTION[14]:                       dhcp_lease_time = 82715
DHCP4.OPTION[15]:                       ip_address = 192.168.38.205
DHCP4.OPTION[16]:                       requested_static_routes = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[17]:                       dhcp_message_type = 5
DHCP4.OPTION[18]:                       requested_domain_name_servers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[19]:                       requested_routers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[20]:                       requested_ntp_servers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[21]:                       subnet_mask = 255.255.255.0
DHCP4.OPTION[22]:                       routers = 192.168.38.1
DHCP4.OPTION[23]:                       domain_name_servers = 192.168.15.10 192.168.15.193
DHCP4.OPTION[24]:                       requested_netbios_name_servers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[25]:                       ntp_servers = 192.168.38.1
DHCP4.OPTION[26]:                       network_number = 192.168.38.0
DHCP4.OPTION[27]:                       requested_host_name = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[28]:                       dhcp_server_identifier = 192.168.38.1
IP6.ADDRESS[1]:                         fe80::780b:205:9775:1a78/64
IP6.GATEWAY:                            

SSID                        BSSID              MODE   CHAN  FREQ      RATE       SIGNAL  BARS  SECURITY   ACTIVE  * 
Highwoods-Guest             <MAC 'Highwoods-Guest' [AN1]>  Infra  1     2412 MHz  54 Mbit/s  100     ▂▄▆█  --         no        
Highwoods-Guest             <MAC 'Highwoods-Guest' [AN2]>  Infra  161   5805 MHz  54 Mbit/s  100     ▂▄▆█  --         no        
DIRECT-96-HP M452 LaserJet  <MAC 'DIRECT-96-HP M452 LaserJet' [AN3]>  Infra  6     2437 MHz  54 Mbit/s  87      ▂▄▆█  WPA2       no        
Highwoods-Guest             <MAC 'Highwoods-Guest' [AN4]>  Infra  11    2462 MHz  54 Mbit/s  84      ▂▄▆█  --         no        
belkin.54a.guests           <MAC 'belkin.54a.guests' [AN5]>  Infra  1     2412 MHz  54 Mbit/s  80      ▂▄▆_  --         no        
belkin.54a                  <MAC 'belkin.54a' [AN6]>  Infra  1     2412 MHz  54 Mbit/s  80      ▂▄▆_  WPA1 WPA2  no        
belkin.54a.media            <MAC 'belkin.54a.media' [AN7]>  Infra  36    5180 MHz  54 Mbit/s  75      ▂▄▆_  WPA1 WPA2  no        
CoulterandSierra-5G         <MAC 'CoulterandSierra-5G' [AN8]>  Infra  40    5200 MHz  54 Mbit/s  72      ▂▄▆_  WPA2       no        
Highwoods-Guest             <MAC 'Highwoods-Guest' [AN9]>  Infra  52    5260 MHz  54 Mbit/s  67      ▂▄▆_  --         no        
CoulterandSierra            <MAC 'CoulterandSierra' [AN10]>  Infra  2     2417 MHz  54 Mbit/s  54      ▂▄__  WPA2       yes     * 
Jeff’s iPhone               <MAC 'Jeff’s iPhone' [AN11]>  Infra  6     2437 MHz  54 Mbit/s  54      ▂▄__  WPA2       no        
YatesNet-Guest              <MAC 'YatesNet-Guest' [AN12]>  Infra  10    2457 MHz  54 Mbit/s  47      ▂▄__  WPA1 WPA2  no        
ATTTB4pGs2                  <MAC 'ATTTB4pGs2' [AN13]>  Infra  11    2462 MHz  54 Mbit/s  47      ▂▄__  WPA1 WPA2  no        
--                          <MAC '--' [AN14]>  Infra  1     2412 MHz  54 Mbit/s  44      ▂▄__  WEP        no        

##### NetworkManager.state ##############

[main]
NetworkingEnabled=true
WirelessEnabled=true
WWANEnabled=true

##### NetworkManager.conf ###############

[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile,ofono
dns=dnsmasq

[ifupdown]
managed=false

##### NetworkManager profiles ###########

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/CoulterandSierra]] (600 root)
[connection] id=CoulterandSierra | type=wifi | permissions=user:hcuellart:;
[wifi] bssid=<MAC 'CoulterandSierra' [AN10]> | mac-address=<MAC 'wlp1s0' [IF1]> | mac-address-blacklist= | ssid=CoulterandSierra
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/Highwoods-Guest_5GEXT]] (600 root)
[connection] id=Highwoods-Guest_5GEXT | type=wifi | permissions=user:hcuellart:;
[wifi] mac-address=<MAC 'wlp1s0' [IF1]> | mac-address-blacklist= | ssid=Highwoods-Guest_5GEXT
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/belkin.9fd]] (600 root)
[connection] id=belkin.9fd | type=wifi | permissions=user:hcuellart:;
[wifi] bssid=<MAC address> | mac-address=<MAC 'wlp1s0' [IF1]> | mac-address-blacklist= | ssid=belkin.9fd
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/Highwoods-Guest_2GEXT]] (600 root)
[connection] id=Highwoods-Guest_2GEXT | type=wifi | permissions=user:hcuellart:;
[wifi] mac-address=<MAC 'wlp1s0' [IF1]> | mac-address-blacklist= | ssid=Highwoods-Guest_2GEXT
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/CoulterandSierra-5G]] (600 root)
[connection] id=CoulterandSierra-5G | type=wifi | permissions=
[wifi] mac-address=<MAC 'wlp1s0' [IF1]> | mac-address-blacklist= | ssid=CoulterandSierra-5G
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/NETGEAR54]] (600 root)
[connection] id=NETGEAR54 | type=wifi | permissions=user:hcuellart:;
[wifi] mac-address=<MAC 'wlp1s0' [IF1]> | mac-address-blacklist= | ssid=NETGEAR54
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/Highwoods-Guest]] (600 root)
[connection] id=Highwoods-Guest | type=wifi | permissions=user:hcuellart:;
[wifi] mac-address=<MAC 'wlp1s0' [IF1]> | mac-address-blacklist= | ssid=Highwoods-Guest
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/Linksys16571]] (600 root)
[connection] id=Linksys16571 | type=wifi | permissions=user:hcuellart:;
[wifi] bssid=<MAC address> | mac-address=<MAC 'wlp1s0' [IF1]> | mac-address-blacklist= | ssid=Linksys16571
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/HOME-EA72]] (600 root)
[connection] id=HOME-EA72 | type=wifi | permissions=user:hcuellart:;
[wifi] bssid=<MAC address> | mac-address=<MAC 'wlp1s0' [IF1]> | mac-address-blacklist= | ssid=HOME-EA72
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/xfinitywifi]] (600 root)
[connection] id=xfinitywifi | type=wifi | permissions=user:hcuellart:;
[wifi] mac-address=<MAC 'wlp1s0' [IF1]> | mac-address-blacklist= | ssid=xfinitywifi
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/belkin.9fd.5GHz]] (600 root)
[connection] id=belkin.9fd.5GHz | type=wifi | permissions=
[wifi] bssid=<MAC address> | mac-address=<MAC 'wlp1s0' [IF1]> | mac-address-blacklist= | ssid=belkin.9fd.5GHz
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=ignore

##### iw reg get ########################

Region: America/New_York (based on set time zone)

country US: DFS-FCC
    (2402 - 2472 @ 40), (N/A, 30), (N/A)
    (5170 - 5250 @ 80), (N/A, 17), (N/A)
    (5250 - 5330 @ 80), (N/A, 23), (0 ms), DFS
    (5490 - 5730 @ 160), (N/A, 23), (0 ms), DFS
    (5735 - 5835 @ 80), (N/A, 30), (N/A)
    (57240 - 63720 @ 2160), (N/A, 40), (N/A)

##### iwlist channels ###################

lo        no frequency information.

wlp1s0    32 channels in total; available frequencies :
          Channel 01 : 2.412 GHz
          Channel 02 : 2.417 GHz
          Channel 03 : 2.422 GHz
          Channel 04 : 2.427 GHz
          Channel 05 : 2.432 GHz
          Channel 06 : 2.437 GHz
          Channel 07 : 2.442 GHz
          Channel 08 : 2.447 GHz
          Channel 09 : 2.452 GHz
          Channel 10 : 2.457 GHz
          Channel 11 : 2.462 GHz
          Channel 36 : 5.18 GHz
          Channel 40 : 5.2 GHz
          Channel 44 : 5.22 GHz
          Channel 48 : 5.24 GHz
          Channel 52 : 5.26 GHz
          Channel 56 : 5.28 GHz
          Channel 60 : 5.3 GHz
          Channel 64 : 5.32 GHz
          Channel 100 : 5.5 GHz
          Channel 104 : 5.52 GHz
          Channel 108 : 5.54 GHz
          Channel 112 : 5.56 GHz
          Channel 116 : 5.58 GHz
          Channel 120 : 5.6 GHz
          Channel 124 : 5.62 GHz
          Channel 128 : 5.64 GHz
          Channel 132 : 5.66 GHz
          Channel 136 : 5.68 GHz
          Channel 140 : 5.7 GHz
          Channel 149 : 5.745 GHz
          Channel 153 : 5.765 GHz
          Current Frequency:2.417 GHz (Channel 2)

##### iwlist scan #######################

lo        Interface doesn't support scanning.

wlp1s0    Failed to read scan data : Resource temporarily unavailable

##### module infos ######################

[rtl8821ae]
filename:       /lib/modules/4.4.0-98-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/realtek/rtlwifi/rtl8821ae/rtl8821ae.ko
firmware:       rtlwifi/rtl8821aefw.bin
description:    Realtek 8821ae 802.11ac PCI wireless
license:        GPL
author:         Realtek WlanFAE <wlanfae@realtek.com>
srcversion:     24F8423C168B0614A78BA4B
depends:        rtlwifi,rtl_pci,btcoexist,mac80211
intree:         Y
vermagic:       4.4.0-98-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
parm:           swenc:Set to 1 for software crypto (default 0)
 (bool)
parm:           ips:Set to 0 to not use link power save (default 1)
 (bool)
parm:           swlps:Set to 1 to use SW control power save (default 0)
 (bool)
parm:           fwlps:Set to 1 to use FW control power save (default 1)
 (bool)
parm:           msi:Set to 1 to use MSI interrupts mode (default 1)
 (bool)
parm:           debug:Set debug level (0-5) (default 0) (int)
parm:           disable_watchdog:Set to 1 to disable the watchdog (default 0)
 (bool)
parm:           int_clear:Set to 0 to disable interrupt clear before set (default 1)
 (bool)

[rtl_pci]
filename:       /lib/modules/4.4.0-98-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/realtek/rtlwifi/rtl_pci.ko
description:    PCI basic driver for rtlwifi
license:        GPL
author:         Larry Finger    <Larry.FInger@lwfinger.net>
author:         Realtek WlanFAE <wlanfae@realtek.com>
author:         lizhaoming  <chaoming_li@realsil.com.cn>
srcversion:     57269FE92F62991D7C5BAF7
depends:        mac80211,rtlwifi
intree:         Y
vermagic:       4.4.0-98-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 

[rtlwifi]
filename:       /lib/modules/4.4.0-98-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/realtek/rtlwifi/rtlwifi.ko
description:    Realtek 802.11n PCI wireless core
license:        GPL
author:         Larry Finger    <Larry.FInger@lwfinger.net>
author:         Realtek WlanFAE <wlanfae@realtek.com>
author:         lizhaoming  <chaoming_li@realsil.com.cn>
srcversion:     F989B967ED95194367DAE03
depends:        mac80211,cfg80211
intree:         Y
vermagic:       4.4.0-98-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 

[mac80211]
filename:       /lib/modules/4.4.0-98-generic/kernel/net/mac80211/mac80211.ko
license:        GPL
description:    IEEE 802.11 subsystem
srcversion:     6650C3CAD4D44FC694253D3
depends:        cfg80211
intree:         Y
vermagic:       4.4.0-98-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
parm:           minstrel_vht_only:Use only VHT rates when VHT is supported by sta. (bool)
parm:           max_nullfunc_tries:Maximum nullfunc tx tries before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
parm:           max_probe_tries:Maximum probe tries before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
parm:           beacon_loss_count:Number of beacon intervals before we decide beacon was lost. (int)
parm:           probe_wait_ms:Maximum time(ms) to wait for probe response before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
parm:           ieee80211_default_rc_algo:Default rate control algorithm for mac80211 to use (charp)

[cfg80211]
filename:       /lib/modules/4.4.0-98-generic/kernel/net/wireless/cfg80211.ko
description:    wireless configuration support
license:        GPL
author:         Johannes Berg
srcversion:     20950513252BA8F4707EF3C
depends:        
intree:         Y
vermagic:       4.4.0-98-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
parm:           bss_entries_limit:limit to number of scan BSS entries (per wiphy, default 1000) (int)
parm:           ieee80211_regdom:IEEE 802.11 regulatory domain code (charp)
parm:           cfg80211_disable_40mhz_24ghz:Disable 40MHz support in the 2.4GHz band (bool)

##### module parameters #################

[rtl8821ae]
debug: 0
disable_watchdog: N
fwlps: N
int_clear: Y
ips: N
msi: Y
swenc: N
swlps: N

[mac80211]
beacon_loss_count: 7
ieee80211_default_rc_algo: minstrel_ht
max_nullfunc_tries: 2
max_probe_tries: 5
minstrel_vht_only: Y
probe_wait_ms: 500

[cfg80211]
bss_entries_limit: 1000
cfg80211_disable_40mhz_24ghz: N
ieee80211_regdom: 00

##### /etc/modules ######################

##### modprobe options ##################

[/etc/modprobe.d/amd64-microcode-blacklist.conf]
blacklist microcode

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-ath_pci.conf]
blacklist ath_pci

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf]
blacklist evbug
blacklist usbmouse
blacklist usbkbd
blacklist eepro100
blacklist de4x5
blacklist eth1394
blacklist snd_intel8x0m
blacklist snd_aw2
blacklist i2c_i801
blacklist prism54
blacklist bcm43xx
blacklist garmin_gps
blacklist asus_acpi
blacklist snd_pcsp
blacklist pcspkr
blacklist amd76x_edac

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-rare-network.conf]
alias net-pf-3 off
alias net-pf-6 off
alias net-pf-9 off
alias net-pf-11 off
alias net-pf-12 off
alias net-pf-19 off
alias net-pf-21 off
alias net-pf-36 off

[/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf]
remove iwlwifi \
(/sbin/lsmod | grep -o -e ^iwlmvm -e ^iwldvm -e ^iwlwifi | xargs /sbin/rmmod) \
&& /sbin/modprobe -r mac80211

[/etc/modprobe.d/mlx4.conf]
softdep mlx4_core post: mlx4_en

[/etc/modprobe.d/rtl8821ae.conf]
options rtl8821ae fwlps=0 ips=0

##### rc.local ##########################

exit 0

##### pm-utils ##########################

##### udev rules ########################

##### dmesg #############################

[ 3225.578430] wlp1s0: authenticate with <MAC 'CoulterandSierra' [AN10]>
[ 3225.584105] wlp1s0: send auth to <MAC 'CoulterandSierra' [AN10]> (try 1/3)
[ 3225.587315] wlp1s0: authenticated
[ 3225.588001] wlp1s0: associating with AP with corrupt probe response
[ 3225.589462] wlp1s0: associate with <MAC 'CoulterandSierra' [AN10]> (try 1/3)
[ 3225.595289] wlp1s0: RX AssocResp from <MAC 'CoulterandSierra' [AN10]> (capab=0x411 status=0 aid=1)
[ 3225.721483] wlp1s0: associated
[ 3612.192771] wlp1s0: deauthenticating from <MAC 'CoulterandSierra' [AN10]> by local choice (Reason: 3=DEAUTH_LEAVING)
[ 3614.999836] wlp1s0: authenticate with <MAC 'Highwoods-Guest' [AN2]>
[ 3615.004973] wlp1s0: send auth to <MAC 'Highwoods-Guest' [AN2]> (try 1/3)
[ 3615.006330] wlp1s0: authenticated
[ 3615.010369] wlp1s0: associate with <MAC 'Highwoods-Guest' [AN2]> (try 1/3)
[ 3615.012265] wlp1s0: RX AssocResp from <MAC 'Highwoods-Guest' [AN2]> (capab=0x1 status=0 aid=3)
[ 3615.153006] wlp1s0: associated
[ 3615.155343] wlp1s0: Limiting TX power to 22 dBm as advertised by <MAC 'Highwoods-Guest' [AN2]>
[ 3824.792987] wlp1s0: deauthenticating from <MAC 'Highwoods-Guest' [AN2]> by local choice (Reason: 3=DEAUTH_LEAVING)
[ 3827.701699] wlp1s0: authenticate with <MAC 'CoulterandSierra' [AN10]>
[ 3827.706023] wlp1s0: send auth to <MAC 'CoulterandSierra' [AN10]> (try 1/3)
[ 3827.709939] wlp1s0: authenticated
[ 3827.712991] wlp1s0: associating with AP with corrupt probe response
[ 3827.716236] wlp1s0: associate with <MAC 'CoulterandSierra' [AN10]> (try 1/3)
[ 3827.723389] wlp1s0: RX AssocResp from <MAC 'CoulterandSierra' [AN10]> (capab=0x411 status=0 aid=1)
[ 3827.868084] wlp1s0: associated

########## wireless info END ############
```

Comment: Thanks for the editing grooveplex I didn't know how to do it...

Comment: There's nothing you can do from your side. That network either requires logging in somewhere, your device isn't authorized or isn't working properly. Perhaps you should contact the owner...

Comment: Well a Windows computer has access to the same point. My phone also has access to it. Also asked several other people and everyone connects perfectly. Just my computer running Ubuntu is the one with problems...

Comment: There seems to be a DNS problem but just don't know too much about how to make all this changes.

Comment: This is what I get when connected to the open (unsecured router)   DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NO_INTERNET

Answer (score 0):

If your computer can connect to the WiFi Access Point it means that your Computer is just working fine and the Connection is established correctly.
Now that you don't have internet suggests that there might be an issue at the WiFi Access Point, which is not able to establish an internet connection itself.
I suggest to log into the Web Administration Panel of this WiFi Access Point and to look there for more information.

I have myself a Router that cannot establish Internet Connection because of an Issue with the Internet Provider. But still I can establish a WiFi Connection with this Router from any terminal without any problem.

Comment: Well a Windows computer has access to the same point. My phone also has access to it. Also asked several other people and everyone connects perfectly. Just my computer running Ubuntu is the one with problems...

Comment: @HomeroC I see from your NetworkManager configuration that there are DNS Server within the Intranet at `DHCP4.OPTION[23]:                       domain_name_servers = 192.168.15.10 192.168.15.193` . So I wonder if your internet problem might lie in a DNS Server Issue. Can you send `ping` to any Internet Address like: `ping 4.2.2.1`? Can you send `ping` to any other host within the same Net 192.168.15.XXX , like `ping 192.168.15.204` ?

Comment: Thanks Bodo Hugo, 192.168.15.204 ping statistics ---
4 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 3018ms

Comment: This is what I get when connected to the open (unsecured router) DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NO_INTERNET

Comment: Hi @HomeroC I meant to ping a Host of which you know that it exists in your Net - any of those Windows machines. And another ping to a Host in Internet `ping 4.2.2.1`.

Comment: I looked the Error "_DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NO_INTERNET_" up for you in internet and found that it associated with a DNS Server Issue and it shows in the Chrome Browser. So it is a known Error and you might find further inside at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32045682/dns-probe-finished-bad-config-error the Solution mainly consists in setting up different known DNS Server from the Internet.

Comment: Don't have the other Windows machines here at the moment. Do you think if I do a fresh install and upgrade to 17.10 it might reset all the networking??

Comment: well tried using Chromiun and Firfox and neither of them worked... But I greatly appreciate your time and help

Comment: Ill check the link you provided